# Remove leading characters Python

Tags: python

I would like to remove the leading characters from each line of this file until I find the digit:

File looks like this:

```
* Fail 63779 - Error A
* Fail 64969 - Error B
* Fail 61529 - Error C
* Fail 65068 - Error D
```

My output should be like below:

```
63779 - Error A
64969 - Error B
61529 - Error C
65068 - Error D
```

It woule be even better if I get this output in ascending order of Fail number:

```
61529 - Error C
63779 - Error A
64969 - Error B
65068 - Error D
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If `* Fail ` is fixed string, use `my_string[7:]`

Comment: AS *Fail is a fixed string, I can use my_string[7:] Then output will be: 63779 - Error A
64969 - Error B
61529 - Error C If I like to get output in sorted order based on the digits like 61529 - Error C
63779 - Error A
64969 - Error B
65068 - Error D , can I do it in Python?
65068 - Error D

Answer (score 2):

The regex `\d.*` will match from the first digit in a string until the last non-linebreak character. That means you can use

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    lines = sorted(re.findall("\d.*", f.read()))
```

to get a list of lines sorted lexicographically (not numerically, so be careful if the number of digits varies).

Then you can write that back to a new file like this:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

If you need to sort numerically, you can define a helper function

```
def lint(s):
    return int(re.match(r"\d+", s).group())
```

and use it like this:

```
lines = sorted(re.findall("\d.*", f.read()), key=lint)
```

Example:

```
>>> s = """* Fail 63779 - Error A
... * Fail 64969 - Error B
... * Fail 61529 - Error C
... * Fail 7068 - Error D"""
>>> sorted(re.findall("\d.*", s), key=lint)
['7068 - Error D', '61529 - Error C', '63779 - Error A', '64969 - Error B']
```